# How can I diagnose problems with my Keras LSTM network?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to build an LSTM model in Keras to predict the time to failure of a machine based on various sensor readings. However, I'm unsure how to interpret the output so that I can improve the model. My data is 15 features over 50,000 sequential time steps. Here is the code I have so far:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM

batch_size = 50
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1,
          batch_input_shape=(batch_size, int(len(X_train)/batch_size), 15),
          dropout=0.2,
          stateful=True,
          return_sequences=True))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, 
          epochs=100, shuffle=False, verbose=0)
```

When I plot the targets vs. the predictions, the plot looks like this:
[image: true vs preds]

All of the predictions seem to be in a narrow band with most falling between approximately -0.5 and 0.5. Is there any way to interpret this other than the data does not appear to be a good predictor of the response?

EDIT: Based on the suggestions, I added the following line to the code above:

```
model.add(Dense(1))
```

This resulted in the following target vs predictions plot:
[image]

which seems to be having the same issues I was facing previously.

Comment: An LSTM has tanh() at its output, i.e. gives outputs in range <-1,1>. Your graph suggests that your target is not limited to this domain. Consider adding a Dense layer on top, without any nonlinearity.
Btw. could you show learning curves? Training loss and validation loss?

Comment: agree with dedObed, just add a Dense layer to the end of your NN.